# What is the best way to store some immutable and highly accessed data in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, azure-functions

**Some background** - I am working in a project which requires a kind of headshake authentication. The external service will send a request with a Token, and I will answer with Validator. Then it will send a second request containing the same Token and the data I should store in my database. The token is also used to get a couple extra fields that are required to insert the data in the database. Due to several project constraints and requirements, this "api" is implemented in Serverless (Azure Functions).

Since there are only 100 and something token-validator pairs that are not often updated (I will update manually every month or so), I have decided about not querying the database every time I get an incoming request. Normally I would simply use caching in C#, but since I am working with Functions, the code will be executed in multiple changing processes, which means no shared cache. I also think that using a cache service, such as Redis or Azure Cache would be an overkill.

**My current solution** - Currently, I am storing the data in a Hashtable that maps a Token to a ValidatorModel object that contains the validator and the extra fields I require. It works pretty well, but since it is a big C# object, it is a pain to update, the IDE lags when I open it, etc. I also don't know if it is a good idea to have it hardcoded in C# like that.

**What I have been thinking about** - I was thinking about storing a binary protobuf file that contained my Hashmap object. I am unsure if this would work or perform well.

**My question** - What is the best way do store such data and access it in a performatic way?

Comment: Did you consider some sort of azure blob storage? if you are in azure, the redis option might not be that bad since it;s just a managed service.

Comment: @jpgrassi thank you. I thought about it, but I think accessing a blob storage thousands of times per minute would not be a good idea, specially since I can embed a resource file in my Azure Functions. I have direct access to it in local storage. But I don't know how performant it would be and what is the best format to store this data, i.e. parsing json is slower than protobuf, etc.

Comment: If it is thousands times per minute, deploy function into premium plan instead of consumption, and use combination of an in-memory cache with (optionally) file-based. Also, look toward local key-value store libraries such as leveldb - those libs make it easier to transparently access persistent values through in-memory cache.

Comment: @RomanPolunin thank you. I think migrating to premium is the best I could do. At this point, I created a protobuf file (23 kb) that will be read if the data is not found in the memory cache. It is working quite well.